# How can I access nested cell arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, nested, cell-array

I would like to make a nested cell array as follows:

```
tag = {'slot1'}
info = {' name' 'number' 'IDnum'}
x = {tag , info}
```

And I want to be able to call `x(tag(1))` and have it display `'slot1'`. Instead I am getting this error:

```
??? Error using ==> subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.
```

If I call `x(1)` MATLAB displays `{1x1 cell}`. I want to be able to access the first cell in the list `x` so I can do a string comparison with another string.

I know I can write my own class to do this if MATLAB's built in class does not work but is there a simple trick to solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The return value of `x(1)` is actually a 1-by-1 cell array containing *another* 1-by-1 cell array which itself contains the string `'slot1'`. To access the *contents* of cell arrays (and not just a *subarray* of cells) you have to use curly braces (i.e. ["content indexing"](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br04bw6-108)) instead of parentheses (i.e. ["cell indexing"](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br04bw6-108)).

For example, if you want to retrieve the string `'slot1'` from `x` in order to do a string comparison, you could do it in one of two ways:

```
cstr = x{1};    %# Will return a 1-by-1 cell array containing 'slot1'
str = x{1}{1};  %# Will return the string 'slot1'
```

Then you can use the function [STRCMP](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strcmp.html) with either of the above:

```
isTheSame = strcmp(cstr,'slot1');  %# Returns true
isTheSame = strcmp(str,'slot1');   %# Also returns true
```

The above works because [cell arrays of strings](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f2-47856.html#f2-38312) in MATLAB are handled somewhat interchangeably with strings and character arrays in many built-in functions.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a cell array, you could use a structure:

```
x(1) = struct('tag','slot1','info',{{'something'}}); %# using '1' in case there are many
```

Then, you get the first tag as

```
x(1).tag
```

Alternatively, you could use tag names as fieldnames. If tag names and information are cell arrays, you can pass the cell arrays instead of 'slot1' and 'information here', and you have the structure created in one go.

```
x = struct('slot1','information here')
tagName = 'slot1';
%# access the information via tag names
x.(tagName)
```

Comment: I have faced the same problem but the cause was that I was using the name of my function (by mistake) the same as an already known cell in another function. Mistakes are there to make us learn. I just wanted to share that